# How to I lookup to fields in another table with the same parent (User) with Django templates?

Tags: python, django

I'm pretty new to Django and Python. I've been doing a lot of reading and read through most of the tutorials and documentation.

I've created a simple application and I'm stuck at a point where in a template, I want to be able to get fields from another model with the same parent. In this case I have a basic forum, with the model Post:

```
class Post(models.Model):
    ... 
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, related_name='forum_post_set')
    ...
```

Each post is assigned the User of whoever made the post. Then when displaying the posts in a thread, I am using the Django . template lookup to access fields from the User model:

```
{% for post in post_list %}
    ...
    Posted by {{ post.author.first_name }} {{ post.author.last_name }}
    ...
{% endfor %}
```

I then also have a Profile model which looks up to User as well:

```
class ZProfile(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
    extra_info = models.TextField(max_length=500, blank=True)
```

So my question is, how do I go about getting the field "extra_info" in my posts template using the author ("user") to reference to the user in the profile model. I have tried things like this:

```
{{ post.author.extra_info }}
{{ post.author.zprofile.extra_info }}
{{ post.author.user.zprofile.extra_info }}
```

etc etc.

Am I missing something here? I am obviously doing something wrong or missing a step, but I can't for the life of me find the answers I need in the documentation.

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because `ZProfile` has a `ForeignKey` to `User`, you access it from `User` using `.zprofile_set.0` (even though you specify `unique=True`). You'd be better off using a `OneToOneField` -- then you could use `poll.author.zprofile.extra_info`.

Django's auth app has support for [user profiles which store additional information about users](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/auth/#storing-additional-information-about-users). If you use a `OneToOneField`, you can 'register' your `ZProfile` class using the `AUTH_MODULE_PROFILE` setting, then use `post.author.get_profile.extra_info`

Comment: Ah thank you! I changed the relationship to a OneToOneField and this fixed my problem.

Thanks for your help and quick response! :)